# How can I use CKEditor with Wordpress and let clients edit the content?

Tags: javascript

I'm a designer who scratches at coding and I'm trying to integrate CKEditor with Wordpress because it would be perfect to **my clients to let them edit the text directly on the page**.

Can this be achieve? I already installed CKEditor in my Wordpress installation and it's working. But it let's non logged users change the content.

Something like this:

```
<h1>Massive inline editing</h1>
      
     <div id="container" style="border: 1px solid blue;width: 700px; display:inline-block;padding:5px;">
      
          <h1 contenteditable="true" style="border:1px solid green;">My Client Website</h1>
          
          <div style="border: 1px solid red; float: left;width: 300px;" contenteditable="true">Div that my clients can edit when logged in their Wordpress Account.            
          </div>
          
          <div style="border: 1px solid red; float: right;width: 350px;" contenteditable="false">
             div with contenteditable='false' <br><br>
             Hello <b>CKEditor</b> ...            
          </div>
                      
      </div>
```

http://codepen.io/oyshiu/pen/OWYKmB